# AndroidX ERROR: Failed to resolve: appcompat

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, androidx

When I create a new project, I have these dependencies as default :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Syncing project fails at the beginning and I can't fix it. The error is for `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` gradle can't resolve this dependency.

Error log :

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: appcompat
Affected Modules: app
```

Gradle Module Project :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I checked the download URL and the result is 404 : https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.1.0

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: There is no stacktarce unfortunately. just bunch of failed to resolve. @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Regarding the 404 on `dl.google.com`... give `https://maven.google.com` a try, there you'll find all the libs and after choosing your version you get a link to the `aar`-file, which you could download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly with deleting the Gradle Home (`.gradle`) problem solved. Probably corrupted cache or something had made the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0"

Comment: I'm using Java lang

Comment: Please update your gradle files and all others dependencies.After then clean and Invalidate and restart android studio. i hope this will helpful.

Comment: I've done everything. The only thing which worked was downgrading this dependency to version 1.0.0 but I think it's not a solution.